# vb.net throws object reference is not set to instance of an object as an error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Greetings.

As, I am new to vb.net and am trying to create a simple login form with local sql databsae and I am getting an error as object reference is not set to instance of an object when I am passing my query string to command text as shown below:

```
Public con As SqlConnection = Nothing
Public cmd, cmd1 As SqlCommand
Public sqlrdr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
Public sqladp As SqlDataAdapter
Public ds As DataSet
Public dtbl As DataTable
Public query As String
```

I have defined these in modules and the below code is in login form

```
 Dim frmHomesMarine As New HomesMarine
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConn").ConnectionString
 Dim txtUserId = Trim(UsernameTextBox.Text)
 Dim txtUserPwd = Trim(PasswordTextBox.Text)
 Try
        MessageBox.Show("Hello", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        query = "SELECT UserId, UserPassword FROM TBLUsers WHERE UserId ='" & txtUserId & "';"
        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.Connection = con
        sqladp.SelectCommand = cmd
        sqlrdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlrdr.Read
            If sqlrdr.HasRows Then
                MessageBox.Show("Table has some rows", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            End If
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

I got the connection string from app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConn"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbHomesMarine.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

i changed the name with user friendly name "MyConn"
Anyone knows the cause of the error

Comment: It is resolved as 
 Public con As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Public cmd, cmd1 As New SqlCommand()
    Public sqlrdr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Public sqladp As New SqlDataAdapter

Comment: this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Research how to use parameterised queries, which will greatly reduce the risk. It's very easy to use them with a SqlCommand object.

Comment: Not only what ADyson has mentioned, a user can type in whatever they want for a userid. Thats not properly checking if a user exist and its a correct password, you are not even using it (password) in the query. I would rethink your approach. Also it seems you are using plain text passwords thats wrong, hash them and salt them...

Comment: Hi, can u just sahre a video or file link that creates full info for learning instead of searching each and everything in msdn

Comment: @JSalaria you can easily google it https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+login+form&oq=asp.net+login+form&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j0l3.2384j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8